# _NoDefault.no_default in pandas library

Tags: python, pandas

I have recently seen this in the panda's documentation. Can someone explain this and how can I access the value?

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to use text, not a screen grab.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `no_default` is used as a placeholder when there is no single default value, but rather the default value is context specific.

For example, in [pandas.DataFrame.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) the default value for `other` depends on the dtype of the input data, it can either be `np.nan` (e.g. for floats) or `pd.NA` (e.g. for strings), and so its default value is set to `no_default`.

In the [where source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/12c886a6a2af4262ee2212b96509feb5965075cf/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py#L1245) the `no_default` is used like this:

```
if other is lib.no_default:
    other = self.fill_value
```

You can use `no_default` yourself by importing as follows:

```
from pandas.api.extensions import no_default
```

It appears to be defined [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/12c886a6a2af4262ee2212b96509feb5965075cf/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx#L2782) as the sole member of a `_NoDefault` enum.